# Control a Textbox Line in VB Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to change my code, which now uses multiple textboxes, but basically I need only one textbox. In order not to consume much resources, I want to limit the code and everything is done in a Textbox (Multiline).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Mydpi.Text = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\itemInfo.txt")
        txtIntDraws.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Mydpi.Text)
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(Mydpi.Text)
        Dim strLines() As String = Strings.Split(sr.ReadToEnd, Environment.NewLine)
        TextBox6.Text = strLines.Length
        TextBox6.Text = Val(TextBox6.Text)
        sr.Close()
        Dim TB As TextBox
        For i As Integer = 1 To Val(TextBox6.Text)
            Dim firstBoxList = txtIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",").ToArray
            Dim secondBoxList = txtIntDraws.Lines(i + 1).Split(",").ToList()
            Dim intersectionList = firstBoxList.Intersect(secondBoxList)
            TB = Me.Controls.Find("txtIntDraw" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
            For Each str As String In intersectionList
                TB.AppendText(str & ",")
            Next
            Dim notRepeatedCharacter = firstBoxList.Union(secondBoxList).ToList
            notRepeatedCharacter.RemoveAll(Function(x) intersectionList.Contains(x))
            TB = Me.Controls.Find("txtIntNonI" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
            For Each str As String In firstBoxList
                TB.AppendText(str & ",")
            Next
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

So this Code:  `TB = Me.Controls.Find("txtIntDraw" & i, True).FirstOrDefault`
will need to become

```
Output: txtIntDraw.Lines (i)
```

and the same
  `TB = Me.Controls.Find ("txtIntNonI" & i, True) .FirstOrDefault`

```
Output: TxtIntNonI.Lines (i)
```

But if we do that, I still need to change this code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        AllNumbers1.AddRange(CType(Me.Controls("txtIntDraw" & x), TextBox).Text.Split(CChar(",")))
End Sub
```

and this should be done in a multiline textbox. `(TxtIntDraw.Lines(i))`

Thanks. So my question is how do I make this code so I can control the textbox line?

Comment: Empty Catch blocks are the devil's workshop. :-) I know you may have left it blank for brevity but it will swallow errors so you never know what's wrong.

Comment: The `For` loop currently starts at 1, which skips the first line of the TextBox.  Is that on purpose, or is this a bug?

Comment: So basically you want to REPLACE the line in the original TextBox with the results?...or do you want to add the results to the END of the current line?

Comment: Replace the result to be in line I of the textbox. The line starts at 1, not from 0, because that's what I wanted.

Comment: TB = Me.Controls.Find("txtIntDraw" & i, True).FirstOrDefault

Comment: I'm on the road right now, so I might not get back to this until Friday or Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder. Google the .net class for more details.

```
'At the top of the file
Imports System.Text

Private Sub FillTextBox()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    'inside the loop
    sb.AppendLine("what ever")
    'and after the loop
    'This will prevent the textbox from having to repaint on every iteration
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

I hope this gives you enough so you can integrate it into your code.

Comment: I'm not yet so advanced that I know how to apply the correct code, but I will give my power... endeavor.